# How to remove "display name" from edit user

Tags: users

I'm building a site that leverages the user email address for the user login instead of a username (via modules [Logintoboggan](https://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan)  & [Email Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/email_registration)). I'm also using [Real Name](https://www.drupal.org/project/realname) to display the "first name" field of the user instead of the username.

My solution is working perfectly apart from when the user is on the edit user account page (and some native drupal system notification message), which displays a "Display Name" field instead of the desired "first name" field.

Question: **How can I remove/delete the "Display Name" field from the edit profile page and Drupal system messages/notification fields?**

[image: "Display name" field on user registration form]

[image: system notification message showing display name "penny_144"]

Comment: Where do the First Name, Last Name, Display name fields come from? Did you create them? Or are they brought by any module you mentioned?

Comment: I defined them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one was easy. To hide any field from the user edit form simply set the `'#access'` to this field to `FALSE` or any other logic you desire. The second one was more difficult. Turned out the display name was still used on the password reset page. That's how we finally solved it:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form__alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { 

  if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form') { 
    $form['account']['name']['#access'] = FALSE; 
  } 

  if ($form_id == 'user_pass_reset') {
    // Here we take the corresponding user ID from the URL, second argument
    $user_id = arg(2);
    // Then we load the user
    $user = user_load($user_id);
    // Now we have the mail
    $user_mail = $user->mail;

    // extracting the date string with a helper function
    $sub_text = getContents($form['message']['#markup'], '<em class="placeholder">', '</em>');
    $expiration_date = $sub_text[1];

    // Now we alter the existing form
    $form['message']['#markup'] = '<p>This is a one-time login for <em class="placeholder">'.$user_mail.'</em> and will expire on <em class="placeholder">'.$expiration_date.'</em>.</p><p>Click on this button to log in to the site and change your password.</p>';
  }
}

/**
 * Helper function to extract a string between two given delimiters
 * Credit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27078384/2199525
 */
function getContents($str, $startDelimiter, $endDelimiter) {
  $contents = array();
  $startDelimiterLength = strlen($startDelimiter);
  $endDelimiterLength = strlen($endDelimiter);
  $startFrom = $contentStart = $contentEnd = 0;
  while (false !== ($contentStart = strpos($str, $startDelimiter, $startFrom))) {
    $contentStart += $startDelimiterLength;
    $contentEnd = strpos($str, $endDelimiter, $contentStart);
    if (false === $contentEnd) {
      break;
    }
    $contents[] = substr($str, $contentStart, $contentEnd - $contentStart);
    $startFrom = $contentEnd + $endDelimiterLength;
  }
  return $contents;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but where do I specifically add this code? I am a front end developer with zero experience in this area of Drupal ☺️

Comment: What about tokens or string overrides? Could I leverage any of these modules to assist?

Comment: @Andy - Tokens or String Overrides. You have to find out. Don't know any of these modules. The code I have in my answer needs to be put into a very simple custom module. All it needs is a `.info` and a `.module` file. Inside the `.module` file you have to place that code. Look for tutorials about creating custom modules in Drupal. There are plenty. Believe me, it's worth learning and it's not so difficult as it sounds first.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Andy - If you have a custom backend theme you could also paste that code in this theme's `template.php` and name it `function MYTHEME_form_user_profile_form_alter(...)`. But if not, go with the module approach. You then later also can put other custom code inside there. Also have a look at the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module. After installation you have a function `dpm()`. Calling `dpm($form)` inside the code of my answer will output you the correct name of your field and much more. You're welcome!

Comment: I have added the following code to my custom template's template.php file'

Comment: I have added the following code to my custom template's template.php file.

<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function wannalift_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['field_display_name']['#access'] = FALSE;
}

I have the Devel module installed but I'm not familiar with how/where to call a function as you described. I assume I need to do this to update the function you showed me with the specific form id of the form field that I wish to remove?

Comment: @Andy – If you'ld simply use `function THEMENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
  dpm($form_id);
}` you'll get the form's ID. As your problem is on the user profile page it very likely will be `form_user_profile`. So you already should be at the right place. Now you need to clear the cache to make Drupal detect your new function. With `dpm($form)` you'll get a clickable field on the user profile page with lots of info inside. Replace `field_display_name` with your correct field name. You maybe named it differently.

Comment: ok so I've added this exact code:

function THEMENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) dpm($form_id); }

But I get a error when browsing to the site:


Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'dpm' (T_STRING), expecting '{' in /site/sites/all/themes/wanna-lift/template.php on line 7

Does "THEMENAME" need to be the exact name of my custom theme?

When you say "you'll get the form's ID" where will I see the form's id exactly when the above works correctly?

Comment: @Andy - At least something is happen. 'Though it's just an error for now. You are on the right track. You do this in the backend theme's template.php, right? Yes, THEMENAME needs to be the machine name (folder name) of your backend theme. The code you provided is missing a curly bracket like the error message states. It should look like `function functioname(arguments) { code; }`. You'll see the form ID on the edit user profile page or on any other backend page that displays a form.

Comment: it is in my themes's template.php. I figured out that my theme name "wanna-lift" had a hiphen in the name which Drupal didn't like. So I deactivated the theme, renamed it, then added: <?php

/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */

function wannalift_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) dpm($form_id); }

Now seeing the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'dpm' (T_STRING), expecting '{' in /Users/Andrew/Sites/_freelance/wanna-lift/site/sites/all/themes/wannalift/template.php on line 7

Comment: @Andy - Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29663/discussion-between-leymannx-and-andy).